# kibana service not running

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to install Elastic search, Nginx, Kibana and Sense.

I am following this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

I successfully installed Elastic search.

However I am stuck at Kibana.

I successfully followed all steps however:

```
root@dev:~# service kibana start
kibana started
root@dev:~# service kibana status
kibana is not running
```

When I run kibana service it says it started, and after that when I want to check if kibana is running, it says it is not running.

If more details are needed for this question to be answered, comment and I will provide it.

Comment: You can try starting kibana from command line and see what it does on startup, by running - `./bin/kibana`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use curl localhost:5601 to test if kibana is really working.
If not working , go to etc/kibana/  to modify the config to check if host is 0.0.0.0 and port is 5601
And the other problem is that your server'memories are not enough for kibana starting.
Hope you can provider the kibana log.

try use:
`journalctl -u kibana.service`
to show the log.

Answer (score 3):

Even I was facing the same issue.

I have installed the latest version of kibana ( Version: 5.0.2) which is dowloaded from this site:
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana

And I have installed the Elasticsearch of version ( 5.0.2)
I used the below site:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-targz.html

It worked for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed older version of kibana or using nginx to wrap to kibana then the following command will not work

```
service kibana start
```

To start or stop service, instead of the above, use the following command:

```
systemctl start kibana.service
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Kibana process failed to start or execute. (I would reckon it is an issue with the kibana.yml file.) You can see why in the Kibana log output. However, Kibana doesn't have a log file by default. You can set it up using the `log_file` Kibana server property.

Have a look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-server-properties.html

Comment: so I set `logging.dest: log_file`. Where is the file stored?

Comment: Well, you decide. I'd probably set it to /tmp/kibana.log. Make sure you disable this option after you figure out the reason for Kibana not starting properly.

Comment: LInk in answer is not valid anymore. The working link -
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.0/settings.html